# Internal server error with using blueimp file uploader

Tags: jquery, nginx, blueimp, jquery-file-upload

I downloaded the latest version of the [files](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

I uploaded them onto my server which constitutes:

- A raspberry pi with the latest Debian image: `2012-08-08-wheezy-armel.img`
- nginx 1.2.1
- PHP 5.4.4

To ensure large files can be uploaded I have added `client_max_body_size 20M;` to the nginx site configuration file.

I have increased the following limits in the php.ini file:

```
upload_max_filesize 9G
post_max_size 9G
max_execution_time 200
max_input_time 200
memory_limit 256M
```

All site files and directories are owned by the user `www-data` which is the user under which nginx runs and this has been checked against the nginx config file.

All files seem to upload fine but upon completion an "internal server error" message is displayed next to each file that has been uploaded.

The nginx server logs an http 500 error logged for the `index.html` request. If 5 files were uploaded, there are 5 such errors logged.

Please can you guide me on how to debug this issue further? I believe all per-requisites, permissions and are in place and not sure where else I should look to try an debug this further. Many thanks.